# What would be the average value of font height vs font width?

Tags: fonts, typography

What would be the average value of font height vs font width?

If we consider common fonts, do they tend to follow a certain ratio for the height vs the width of each glyph? Is there a standard value or a reasonable average?

Or is there no pattern to this?

Comment: I suppose it would ultimately average out to 1:1. Fonts come in all shapes and sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height/width ratio depends on the particular typeface, some (e.g., Times Roman) being inherently narrower than others (such as Bookman). Many typefaces have Compressed, Condensed, Regular and/or Extended fonts in the family. Obviously the height/width average is very different for each. The range spans a wide spectrum from the incredibly narrow (Universe 39 Thin Ultra-Condensed) to the ridiculously wide (Blackoak).

Depending on the needs of a particular project, a designer will choose a wider or narrower typeface.